# Access same variable with 2 different dimension using Unions

Tags: c, unions, misra, type-punning

I have to following issue: I'm using this king of structures to access the same variable but with different size.

```
typedef struct {
        union {
            struct {
                uint16 progressNumber;
            };
            uint8 progressNumberArr[2];
        };
} ProgressNum_t;
ProgressNum_t totalProgressiveNumber;
```

In this way I can access to a 8bit array (it is useful for SPI communications) and also to manage a 16-bit variable. In my case it's a counter, and I have to manage overflows and so on...

This procedure works fine, but for MISRA rules I'm not allowed to use it (because the behaviour could be undefined).

Do you have any suggestion to have the same "trick" but MISRA-compliant?

Comment: You should be using `stdint.h` and not some home-made flavour of it.

Answer (score 2):

It's an advisory rule - you need to read rule 19.2 in detail. It comes with exceptions.

The behavior of this code is *not* undefined and type punning like this - serialization/deserialization with a character type like `uint8_t` - is one of the valid uses of unions. Unlike for example creating "variant" types through `union`, which is highly questionable practice.

The most important rationale behind this MISRA rule is that the same region of memory should never be used for *unrelated* purposes. This isn't the case in your example, each union member refers to the same data with the same binary representation.

The code is endianess-dependent however. As mentioned in 19.2 you need to consider padding/alignment and endianess both when deviating from the rule.

If you wish to strictly follow MISRA-C then you could drop the union, declare a plain `uint16_t` and just use bit shifts to mask out MS byte and LS byte. That way the code turns portable too, regardless of endianess.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Lundin's answer, the Rule is there to prevent you doing all the bad things that `union`s allow you to do... but because it is *Advisory* it allows you to use the `union` keyword where it is safe to do so, with minimal fuss (ie without a formal deviation)

But if you do use a `union`, make sure you understand what you are doing...

A union of an element paired with an `unsigned char` array is generally OK - as long as you are mindful of implementation-defined portability issues (eg endian-ness)

--
See profile for affiliation